# Причина выбора максимального значения unsigned char

Tags: c, c++

Почему стандарт целочисленных типов в С требует, чтобы значение `unsigned char` не превышало `(2 ^ CHAR_BIT) - 1`? Непонятно, зачем нужен `- 1`.

Comment: Вы кажется случайно пару слов в вашем вопросе.

Answer (score 8):

Потому что отсчет всегда с нуля начинается.

Answer (score 2):

"Не превышало" - это значит, что может быть и равно.
И как вы разместите число 2<sup>8</sup>=256 (=100000000 в битовом представлении) в 8 битах?...